# How to read my css file with express, node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm a beginner in express, node.js.

I try to build my app but my style.css file is not read and I don't understand why.

At the beginning, I try to do with .scss but when I search about that, I've learned that it can't possible.

So I transform my style.scss in style.css and it's the same result when I run my app : my style is not apply and  in the inspector I've this message :

> localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from
> 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html')
> is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is
> enabled.

When I click on the link 'http://localhost:3000/style.css', this message appear in the tab:

> Cannot GET /style.css

Here my code in my index.js :

```
const express = require('express'); 
const {engine} = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.engine('handlebars', engine({
    layoutsDir:__dirname + '/views/layouts',
}));

app.set('view engine','handlebars');
   
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('main', {layout : 'index'})
});
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => 
console.log(`Notre app est lancée sur : http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

In my index.handlebars I have the line in my :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./style.css">
```

In my code, when I ctrl+click on "./style.css", I find the right css file.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Can you confirm that `style.css` is in the `public` folder?

Comment: yes, with all the others

Comment: this is my html code in my index.handlebars:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>bot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>`

and in my {{{body}}} in my main.handlebars you have the html code like <h1></h1> etc.

Comment: And when I put a color  like <h1 style="color:red"> in my index or in my main, it works for the both

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/express-simple-maojij). It looks like Express is not serving the css from the `public` folder. Does it correctly work for other static resources in the same folder?

Comment: when I put the css in the layouts folder it doesn't work
if you want to see: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/express-simple-u2rang?file=views/layouts/index.handlebars

Comment: Well, that's why I asked you if `style.css` was in the `public` folder... And you answered it was. But if you put it in the `layout` folder then it is no longer in the `public` folder. You are serving static content from `public`, so the file _must_ be in the `public` folder.

Comment: yes, the first time it was in `public` folder, after I try to put it in the same folder than `index.handlebars` , both don't work

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear. (1) As long as you're serving static content from `public` the css file must definitely be in that folder. (2) I can see from your own stackblitz that css is correctly loaded when put in the right (public) folder. So, what does it mean "both dont' work"?

Comment: Maybe it's me who don't understand very well, sorry. 
I saw on stackblitz that it worked, but in my code no. 
Maybe my project is not correctly install ?
I'll go to restart and see if it's okay
Until then, thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that `style.css` is in the `public` folder

the only problem that remains in your `index.js` code is `app.use(express.static('public'));` you mast add it before rendering your pages

### example:

```js
const express = require('express'); 
const {engine} = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.engine('handlebars', engine({
    layoutsDir:__dirname + '/views/layouts',
}));

app.set('view engine','handlebars');

app.use(express.static('public'));
   
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, () => 
console.log(`Notre app est lancée sur : http://localhost:${port}`);
);
```